# Hibernate Interceptor post insert

Tags: hibernate

I want to intercept all inserted entities.

There are `onSave` which is pre-insert entity and `postFlush` which contains both insert and update entity.

How to only get post-insert entity(s) via Hibernate Interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Hibernate Interceptors - you may be able to identify inserts in say for example onFlushDirty(...) if the previous state has null id, provided you are not manually assigning id's but generating them.